# Accessing forms created through LWUIT resource editor using code

Tags: lwuit, lwuit-resource-editor, lwuit-form

I am trying to develop a quiz application using LWUIT resource editor and am having great difficulty.

I have created two `Forms` 'GUI1' and 'GUI2' .

GUI1 displays the following:

1. A question(in the form of a `TextField`)
2. 5 `RadioButtons` belonging to the same group
3. A `Button` which says 'OK'

GUI2 displays the following:

1. A `TextField`
2. A `Button` to go back to GUI1

Now the problem is:

Initially GUI1 is displayed. When the user chooses a `RadioButton` , I wish to know which `RadioButton` was selected. If that `RadioButton` was indeed the correct answer, then when the user clicks on the 'OK' `Button` on GUI1, I wish to  display the text 'correct' in the `TextField` on GUI2 and then display the GUI2.

If the user chose the wrong answer, then I wish to display the text "Wrong" in the `TextField` on GUI2 and then display the GUI2.

How can this be done with resource editor? I am very foxed. Please help.
I wish to refer to the `TextField` on GUI2 when I am currently on GUI1. How can this be done with resource editor? Writing a manual code for all this would be very time consuming.

Comment: Have you tried these links [UIBuilder class](http://www.lwuit.com/2010/10/ui-builder-class-how-to-actually-use.html),    

LWUIT Resource Editor for developer series [1](http://www.lwuit.com/2010/11/new-resource-editor-tutorial-part-1.html), [2](http://www.lwuit.com/2010/11/second-part-of-new-resource-editor.html), [3](http://www.lwuit.com/2010/11/lwuit-resource-editor-tutorial-part-3.html), [4](http://www.lwuit.com/2010/11/lwuit-resource-editor-tutorial-part-4.html), [5](http://www.lwuit.com/2010/11/lwuit-resource-editor-tutorial-part-4.html),

Comment: Lwuit Resource Editor for developer series [6](http://www.lwuit.com/2010/12/lwuit-resource-editor-tutorial-part-6.html), [7](http://www.lwuit.com/2010/12/lwuit-resource-editor-tutorial-part-7.html), [8](http://www.lwuit.com/2010/12/lwuit-resource-editor-tutorial-part-8.html), [9](http://www.lwuit.com/2011/01/lwuit-resource-editor-tutorial-part-9.html), [10](http://www.lwuit.com/2011/01/lwuit-resource-editor-tutorial-part-10.html)

Comment: To provide some pointers you need to bind your resource editor generated netbeans project with some code. So in your case the decision to move to 'GUI2' should be written in the resource editor generated netbeans project. Its pretty easy to bind your logic into the resource editor generated project. For example refer my [github project](https://github.com/vimcool/lwuit-widgets/tree/master/LwuitIndicatorWidgetTest), check the class [StateMachine](https://github.com/vimcool/lwuit-widgets/blob/master/LwuitIndicatorWidgetTest/src/userclasses/StateMachine.java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I will try to explain the best I can.

When you design the first `Form` GUI1 the five `RadioButtons` must be in the same group. I don't know how to do that in the resource editor (I think there is a field called ButtonGroup in the `RadioButton`, but I can't remeber). What I would do is take the five `RadioButton` by code in the before method of GUI1 and add them to a `ButtonGroup` element.

With `ButtonGroup` you can know which element is selected using `ButtonGroup.setSelectedIndex()`. When you press the `Button` take this value and act as appropriate to the situation.

If you don't understand anything please tell me and I will try to help you.
Is not a hard thing to do.  There must be a way to do it with the Resoruce editor but at the moment I don´t know how.

Comment: In the GUI of the resource editor properties palette you have a "Group" property. Just give radio buttons the same group name and they will share a group. You can just listen to an action event on the radio button to know the selected answer.

Answer (score 0):

As Shai mentioned, the best thing to do is to use listeners to set the "state" of the buttons on clicking them and when you move to the next form you just retrieve the state of the previous text field.

Manual code may actually be faster for you, do most of the UI in the resource editor and transfer to a form that is written manually. That way you have full control over your objects and transfer back into the GUI builder form when needed.